# Generic function typedef in C - how to get rid of initialization warning?

Tags: c, generics, c11, cortex-m, stm32f7

I'm experimenting with generic-like code and I have a function like this (a lot of not relevant code removed):

```
typedef uint8_t (*struct_converter_t)(void *, char *);

void convert_struct(
        struct_converter_t converter, // this is a function
        const char * file_name
){
    some_struct_t * some_struct;
    converter(some_struct, some_string_buffer);
}
```

And when I try to assign a function that takes `some_struct_t` (not `void *`):

```
static uint8_t some_converter(some_struct_t * vd, char * s);
```

to my `struct_converter_t` like this:

```
struct_converter_t converter = some_converter;    // WARNING HERE
```

I'm getting this:

> initialization of 'struct_converter_t' {aka 'unsigned char (*)(void *,  char *)'} from incompatible pointer type 'uint8_t (*)(some_struct_t *,  char *)' {aka 'unsigned char (*)(struct <anonymous> *,  char *)'} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

I'm not experienced in C and I would like to know if there is a way to get rid of this warning elegantly.

Comment: I think it's just telling you that the callback is expecting a void* type but you're passing in a struct type.. By the way are you compiling this as C or C++? Because I believe in C++ you're forced to explicitly cast but in C the compiler should implicitly do it for you

Comment: How is `convert_struct` being called?  How are the parameters being passed in declared?  Please update your question with a [mcve] that contains all relevant details.

Comment: Well, this code is actually it. I have added compiler and machine information. I't "doesnt like" that I assign pointer of a function that accepts `struct *` as parameter into type that is a function pointer that accepts `void *`.

Comment: The warning message seems not to appear in the code that you posted but in the line where you call the function "`convert_struct`". The warning message typically comes with a line number. Please check which line the warning message applies to.

Comment: @Yuumi how can I explicitly cast pointer assignment?

Comment: @MartinRosenau The warning is about the line where I assign function pointer, not where I call the function.

Comment: @Kamil  try `(void*)some_struct` to cast

Comment: Sorry about missing code and pasted image. Now I fixed everything and I'm wondering about better title for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function that you're assigning to the function pointer type has parameters that are incompatible with the function pointer.

Your function takes a `some_struct_t *` as the first parameter but the function pointer type takes a `void *` as the first parameter.  While any object pointer can be converted to/from a `void *`, that does not extend to function pointer parameters.

You need to change your function to take a `void *` for its first parameter to be compatible with the function pointer.  Then inside the function you can convert that `void *` parameter to a `some_struct_t *`.

Comment: "that does not extend to function pointer parameters" - thanks, that explains everything. I have changed function that is being assigned to my defined function pointer. Inside I simply cast void * to some_struct_t *.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you can supply an argument of type `X*` to a function expecting a `void*`. But that's as far as the conversion goes. You cannot take a function whose first parameter is an `X*` and use it as the argument for a parameter which is a function whose first parameter is a `void*`.

The reason is that C does not guarantee that `X*` and `void*` have the same representation. It does guarantee that the compiler knows how to convert an `X*` into a `void*` in a way that does not destroy information, so that it can be later converted back to an `X*`. But the `void*` might look quite different.

So the compiler can insert code which changes the `X*` to a `void*`. But how does it change a `char*(*)(X*)` (a function whose parameter is an `X*`) to a `char*(*)(void*)`? If the function is expecting that `arg` has type `char*(*)(void*)`, then it will mostly likely call `arg(v)` where `v` has type `void*`. What then happens if `arg` actually expects an `X*`?

In order for the compiler to allow that possibility, it would have to somehow wrap `arg` in what's usually called a trampoline; a function which accepts an `X*` and converts it into a `void*` in order to call a different function. That's not so easy -- for one thing, it would have to store the trampoline somewhere -- so C refuses to do it as an automatic conversion.

Comment: `C refuses to do it` You mean doing it automatically by compiler, right?

Comment: @Kamil: right. You'd have to do it yourself. Which is not a bad idea, since when you try to do it you will see how tricky it is to do in a general way (I added a couple of words to clarify what I meant.)

Comment: nitpicking: the C standard guarantees that `char*` and `void*` have the same representation. Though casting `void(*)(char*)` to `void(*)(void*)` still requires a cast and it is technically an UB.

Comment: @tstanisi: the peculiar exception for `char*` really isn't relevant here, I don't think. In the context of the OP, `X` is `some_struct_t`, and inserting verbiage to attempt to explain the exception would be pedantic obscurantism. I guess I could have just changed `X` to `some_struct_t`, but I didn't, for various reasons. I did take the opportunity to fix the markdown typo, so thanks.